# orientation issue in ios6

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using UINavigationController in my application and my first controller called **A** and it is strict to portrite only and there is a button in my **A** controller.Once I click on the button I am creating instance to the another view controller called **B**. After creating the instance for B I am presenting modally using below method

```
[self presentViewController:BInstance animated:YES completion:^{
            NSLog(@"completed");
        }];
```

My B controller can able will support all the orientations, this is expected, till the ios5.1 and earlier versions. Now I am trying to run my project on the ios6 using Xcode4.5 it is not getting rotated I am looking forward to solve the issue I found some of the blogs about **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:** method got deprecated from the latest ios6. I used alternative also

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But still there is not much expected results.

**Question:** What makes my **B** controller will work for all orientations even my Parent **A** works only for portrite.

Thanks In advance All your suggestions/advice useful on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, in AppDelegate, write this. **THIS IS VERY IMP**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Then, For UIViewControllers, in which you need only **PORTRAIT** mode, write these functions

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

For UIViewControllers, which require **LANDSCAPE** too, change masking to All.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
    //OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Now, if you want to do some changes when Orientation changes, then use this function.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this I am checking.

Comment: I have tried it and then written... So it should work. Did you return YES for shouldAutorotate method in the class where you want LANDSCAPE? Could you post your code?

Comment: +1 now its working..along with all your steps need to include one more step window.rootviecontroller have to be set.Thanks for this.